# ruby can't find installed gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I've installed ruby and the nokogiri gem on my ubuntu linux system, using rvm.

From irb I do "require 'rubygems'". This returns false. Any subsequent attempt to load a gem fails.
Attempts to access the gems from scripts in files also produce "no such file to load..."

So, once I've installed gems with rvm, how to I actually access them?

Comment: How did you install them? Provide a better explanation.

Comment: I followed the instructions on the rvm for a system-wide installation of rvm. Then, as root, I installed ruby 1.9.2-p290. Then I did 'rvm gem install nokogiri', 'rvm gem install mechanize' and 'rvm install rails'. They all install fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should switch to ruby version you installed with RVM:

To get the list of installed rubies:

```
rvm list
#=> rvm rubies
#=>   ree-1.8.7-2011.03 [ x86_64 ]
#=>   ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
```

Then you can run which one you want:

```
rvm 1.9.2
```

Then you can try your gems again

Comment: To get gems to work, I've uninstalled all but one version of ruby. After I uninstalled everything but 1.9.2, I ran 'gem install nokogiri' again, and it ran without issue. But that gem, and as far as I can tell, all others, are still unavailable.